# How to do autocomplete/suggestion search bar in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing a full-stack application using the MEVN stack and I want users to able to search for cards. While the user is typing in the search bar, I want the website to show the user an x amount of options (drop-down list) that they can click on. The list will obviously get narrower the more the user types.

Now, I already know how to do the computed/watch property to filter the list as the user types.

**My issue**: I don't know how to SHOW the list as the user is typing, like the picture below.

The only way I can think of doing it is to have a v-model on a ul element but doesn't seem like the best right way to do it? Everything I've searched for regarding my question deals with the select element, and that's not what I want.

I want something that looks like this picture:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use a select field with search field in it?

Comment: @Rijosh I can use that but I don't want to use that for UX/UI purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to implement something very similar in Vue just a few weeks back. The solution was to use a list (ul) for the results. Essentially what I did was was use a watcher to watch for changes to the search word (and debounce to not flood the server with requests with every time something was typed), and call the API that would return the results that were stored in a property for the component (i.e. in the data of the component).

So something like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <div><input type="text" v-model="searchString"/></div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id">{{ result.label }}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { debounce } from "lodash";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
   name: "SearchThingy",
   data: function() {
     return {
        searchString: "",
        results: []
     }
   },
   watch: {
      searchString: debounce(function () {
        this.search();
      }, 1000),
   },
   methods: {
      search: function() {
         axios.get(`/search?query=${this.searchString}`)
           .then((response) => this.results = this.response.data.results);
      }
   }
};
</script>
```

Now, didn't test it or anything like that, but hopefully this will get you started as your question was a little bit broad.

Answer (score 0):

MEVN u said? So that means you use MongoDB. You should create first and API search endpoint that looks like this:

```
//search.js

import User from "../models/user";
export default async function(req, res) {
   let query = req.body.query;

   if (!query) {
     return res.status(200).json([]);
   }
   const users = await User.aggregate([
     {
       $searchBeta: {
         search: {
           query,
           path: ["name", "surname"],
           phrase: {
             prefix: true
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ]);

   return res.status(200).json(users);
 }
```

Let me explain this aggregation pipeline. First of all you import your mongoose schema (i guess you using mongoose). There is something called `$searchBeta`. The `$searchBeta` stage performs a full-text search on the specified field or fields. In my case i have an input field where i can search users. I am searching in the field `name` and `surname` if there are any hints. the `phrase` is set to `prefix = true`. That means that as soon as you send 1 character to the search API it will try to find the correct result.

The API endpoint will return you an Array with all documents that matches. The matches are sorted by an `searchScore`.

On your frontend you should have something like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="searchbox">
     <input
       @keyup="search"
       placeholder="Search..."
       type="text"
       v-model="query"
    />
    <div
      class="result"
      v-for="result in matchArray"
      :key="result._id"
    >
      <div class="account_box">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
      </div>
      <p>{{ result.name + " " + result.surname }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data(){
      return {
         query: "",
         matchArray: []
      }
   },
   methods: {
      axios.post("/api/search", {
         query: this.query:
      })
      .then(res => {
         matchArray = res.data;
      });
   }
}
</script>
```